# Kerning when inserting symbols from another font

Tags: unicode, kerning, alphabet

I have a METAFONT that implements the shavian alphabet mapping ASCII characters to shavian glyphs, for example the t is the shavian letter 'tot'. I have mapped the shavian letter's unicode representation to the glyphs, like this:

```tex
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10450}{{\shaw p}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10451}{{\shaw t}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10452}{{\shaw k}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10453}{{\shaw f}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10454}{{\shaw X}}
```

This inserts the shavian "p" when I enter the symbol "".  The problem is that the kerning does not work. When I write `{\shaw nt}` it displays the kerning, but if I write  it does not work. This seems to be caused by the grouping. I have tried mapping these symbols like this: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10454}{X}` and enclosing the whole shavian text in `{\shaw }`, but the shaw font lacks punctuation, so it is not a viable alternative.

For example, in the text

```tex
    (1794--1867)   . 
"`"'              
   "`"'
```

the german quoutes (`` "` `` and `"'`), the numbers and the long hyphen (--) should appear in the computer modern font, while the rest appears in the shavian font (which should be properly kerned).

Is there any simple way to achieve kerning while using computer modern's punctuation symbols?

Comment: Welcome. You can't get kerning between characters from different fonts. In this case, that kerning is not even defined.

Comment: @cfr I do not want to get kerning between different fonts, I want to get kerning between the shaw characters, which are all in the same font.

Comment: Hmm... but you are switching fonts in between the characters. A minimal example would help, even if we don't have the font.

Comment: The only answer I can think of here - unless Xe/LuaTeX offers something - is to create a virtual font using letters from the `shaw` font and punctuation from `cmr` or `lmr` or whatever. This is the way you usually create fonts for (pdf)TeX when you want to combine glyphs from different fonts. Once created, you have a new font which TeX will treat as just a regular font. This would not be too hard. `fontinst` can be set up so that it will take everything it can from `shaw` and then fill out empty slots in an encoding from your secondary font. Since there is no punctuation in `shaw`, you...

Comment: don't have to worry about overriding it which would involve additional messing around. Take a look at the Font Installation Guide and decide how badly you want to do this. It isn't especially hard, but it does take time and patience and you need to do the reading in order to understand how to get what you want where you want it.

Comment: (I'm assuming, here, that, you can either do this with metafont or, if necessary, you could convert the font to type1 format. I've never done it for metafont fonts, but the manual for `fontinst` should tell you whether it is possible directly or not. But don't count on the manual for instructions. The Font Installation Guide is much easier to follow.)

Comment: I am giving the fontinst manual a look,  I don't know where the font installation guide is. I think the fontinst tool could do the job.

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/fontinstallationguide. There may be something specific for MetaFont which would serve your needs better. I've never worked with `.mf` fonts so I'm not sure but take a look around on CTAN.

Comment: I think I will just insert Computer Modern's characters in the font. That will force me to improve the font.